# How to deal with apostrophes and double quotes simultaneously in PHP

Tags: php, string, escaping

I have a HTML form, from which a PHP script extracts values, as shown below:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("all required info here...") or die("Error occurred");

$sent = "Any sentence here...which may contain apostrophe or double quotes or both";

$query = "SELECT * FROM myrecord WHERE sentence = '$sent'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

The problem is, that the variable `$sent` can contain any string with a *combination of either apostrophe or double quotes or both*. This gives an error when going for execution of `mysqli_query()`.
So even if I escape double quotes in initialization of `$sent` it will still create problem for execution of `mysqli_query()`. And if I escape both for ' and " then value of `$sent` does not remains what it actually needs to be (although I am not sure about whether escaping both ' and " will work or not).

Is there any built in function that automatically escapes all special characters of a string? Or any workaround that solves this problem?

[P.S. I have already searched some previous questions on stackoverflow and haven't been able to find a solution.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, and what you should do is used prepared statements (parameterized queries). With `PDO`, that would look something like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM myrecord WHERE sentence = :sentence');
$stmt->execute([':sentence' => $sentence]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

`mysqli` supports them, too, but the API is slightly more cumbersome (IMO) - see [`mysqli_prepare` docs](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) for details:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM myrecord WHERE sentence = ?');
//or $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
```

Then, you bind the parameter (the value to be used in the WHERE clause) using [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $sentence);
//or mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $sentence);
```

Then call [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) - or `mysqli_stmt_execute`, and fetch the results using [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) - or `mysqli_stmt_fetch`...

---

As mentioned in the comments: the parameters and query string needn't be quoted in any way, because they're treated as separate entities. The result being that you can re-use the same prepared statement with different paramters:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = :field');
$fieldVals = [123, 46, 32]; // three values:
$results = array_fill_keys($fieldVals, null);
foreach ($fieldVals as $val) {
    $stmt->execute([':field' => $val]);//execute with each value in $fieldVals array
    $results[$val] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // fetch results for this field value
    //optional, but good form:
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

you've now used the same statement 3 times, but only had to send the query string *once*. The query had to be parsed and processed once, and after that, you merely sent the paramters to the DB. This approach is generally faster, safer (prepared statements protect agains most injection attacks), and just all round better.

Comment: Won't this create trouble in `$pdo->prepare()` if the string contains apostrophe?

Comment: @Lincoln You don't need to use the apostrophe anymore.

Comment: @Lincoln: Nope, `:sentence` is a placeholder, it's not an actual part of the query. The way this works is the query, with placeholders is sent to the DB, where it's parsed and an execution plan is built, then, when calling `execute`, the parameter values are sent separately, and put in place, and the _resulting_ query is executed. The upshot is, there's no need to escape characters like quotes anymore, as the parameters and query string are, essentially, processed independently. Another advantage is that you can re-use prepared statements (I'll update the answer with an example)